# KineticJS - Use of coordinates while drawing shape

Tags: canvas, kineticjs

I want to use KineticJS to draw a set of complex shapes in a grid. My shapes are 80 wide and 150 high. When I draw them, there is a gap between the shapes that is the width/height of the shapes - I expected them to be butted up against each other in a tight grid, not separated.

It looks like somehow I'm drawing each shape at twice the x/y that it should be.

I've simplified my problem into the attached code. My shape is complex, but to keep the code simple I've replaced my shapes by rectangles (I know that I could use the Rect object just to draw rectangles).

When you run this code you will see 8 rectangles widely separated both horizontally and vertically; to be clear, what I want is each of the rectangles tightly butted up against each other.

I'm using constants width and height both to draw the rectangles in function drawFunc, and to position the rectangles (in the code `xPos = ((cols -1) * width)` so I would have thought that they would be tight against each other.

The code is pretty simple. I loop through the rows and cols, I create a drawFunc for my shape, I use the width/height in the drawing, and then I position the shape according to its row/col using the same width/height. So they should be tight against each other, not widely separated.

Confused.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://www.kineticjs.com/download/kinetic-v3.9.8.js"></script>

<script>
    window.onload = drawKineticGrid;


    function drawKineticGrid() {

        var width = 80;
        var height = 150;

        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container : "container",
            width : 800,
            height : 600
        });

        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var messageLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        for (rows = 1; rows <= 2; rows++) {

            for (cols = 1; cols <= 4; cols++) {
                var aRect = new Kinetic.Shape({
                    name : "" + rows + ":" + cols,
                    drawFunc :    function() {

                        var context = this.getContext();
                        context.beginPath();

                        // Make a simple shape - my actual shape is more complex, but I'm
                        // writing a rectangle here to keep the code simple - I know I could use

                        // the KineticJS Rect class here instead.

                        context.moveTo(this.getX(), this.getY());
                        context.lineTo(this.getX() + width, this.getY());

                        context.lineTo(this.getX() + width, this.getY() + height);

                        context.lineTo(this.getX(), this.getY() + height);

                        context.lineTo(this.getX(), this.getY());

                        context.lineWidth = 2;
                        context.stroke();

                        this.fill();
                        this.stroke();

                        // Draw the X and Y, Row and Col values in the rectangle
                        context.fillText("x,y : " + this.getX() + ", " + this.getY(), this.getX() + 5, this.getY() + 15);

                        context.fillText("row, col : " + this.getName(), this.getX() + 5, this.getY() + 30);

                    },
                    fill : "#ffffff",
                    stroke : "green",
                    strokeWidth : 1
                });

                //add the  shape to the layer
                var xPos = ((cols - 1) * width);
                var yPos = ((rows - 1) * height);

                aRect.setX(xPos);
                aRect.setY(yPos);
                layer.add(aRect);
            }
        }

        // Add the layer to the stage
        stage.add(layer);
        stage.add(messageLayer);

    };

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you attach an image/screenshot  of how it looks ?

Answer (score 0):

Jaycee,

Have in mind that draw() method occurs after the setX() method;

In the first iteration, everything ok.

In the second iteration, When you do setX(80), your horizontal reference becomes 80px, fine.

Afterward, you call moveTo(80, 0), so the stroke gets positioned in the point(160, 0)   ---> /*80 + 80*/

And so on. Try the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://www.kineticjs.com/download/kinetic-v3.9.8.js"></script>

<script>
    window.onload = drawKineticGrid;


    function drawKineticGrid() {

        var width = 80;
        var height = 150;

        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container : "container",
            width : 800,
            height : 600
        });

        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var messageLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        for (rows = 1; rows <= 2; rows++) {

            for (cols = 1; cols <= 4; cols++) {
                var aRect = new Kinetic.Shape({
                    name : "" + rows + ":" + cols,
                    drawFunc :    function() {

                        var context = this.getContext();
                        context.beginPath();

                        // Make a simple shape - my actual shape is more complex, but I'm
                        // writing a rectangle here to keep the code simple - I know I could use

                        // the KineticJS Rect class here instead.

                        context.moveTo(0, 0);
                        context.lineTo(width, 0);

                        context.lineTo(width, height);

                        context.lineTo(0, height);

                        context.lineTo(0, 0);

                        context.lineWidth = 2;
                        context.stroke();

                        this.fill();
                        this.stroke();

                        // Draw the X and Y, Row and Col values in the rectangle
                        context.fillText("x,y : " + this.getX() + ", " + this.getY(), 5, 15);

                        context.fillText("row, col : " + this.getName(), 5, 30);

                    },
                    fill : "#ffffff",
                    stroke : "green",
                    strokeWidth : 1
                });

                //add the  shape to the layer
                var xPos = ((cols - 1) * width);
                var yPos = ((rows - 1) * height);

                aRect.setX(xPos);
                aRect.setY(yPos);
                layer.add(aRect);
            }
        }

        // Add the layer to the stage
        stage.add(layer);
        stage.add(messageLayer);

    };

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates in drawFunc should be relative (to the point (getX(), getY()), not absolute. For example if you want to draw a rect, use

```
drawFunc: function(canvas){
    var context = canvas.getContext();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, 0);
    context.lineTo(this.getWidth(), 0);
    context.lineTo(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    context.lineTo(0, this.getHeight());
    context.closePath();
    canvas.fillStroke(this);
}
```